binary representation of a PDF file encooded to decoded and previewable format

%PDF-1.5\n%����\n4 0 obj\n<</DecodeParms<</Colors 3/Predictor
15/BitsPerComponent 8/Columns
170>>/Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent
8/Width 170/Length 617/Height
170/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream\nx���Q��0DA���3gL6)���f[�h�ϟ>�c\t��������������������.�R��������KV?~����Ǐ���r.}A8�u�V?~����Ǐ���XYL�����/\nendstream\nendobj\n22
0 obj\n<</Type/XRef/W[1 2 2]/Root 20 0 R/Index[0 23]/ID
[<9968e9eb4d069def87c83bca3f32b371><0ed1f263d4074e258814cda9d1dfa204>]/Length
72/Info 21 0 R/Size 23/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream\nx�%���
C�,����=�J���;��L&��T$8�45��3���;�A���A�\n;������C$�u�|\nendstream\nendobj\nstartxref\n3277\n%%EOF\n

have this pdf data what i wish to do is convert this into buffer's of data which i can preview it's like encoded data i am not able to decode it and save have tried multiple things to do
const decodedPdfData = Buffer.from(rawResponse, 'base64');
const decodedPdfData = Buffer.from(rawResponse, 'binary');

can anyone please let me know way to do this ?
I am expecting pdf buffer's which i can preveiw and save it to cloud but issue is this  while saving through above  method it seems empty or damaged

please help me to resolve this ?

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you're trying to grab the data, you'll need to extract the data between the <stream>...</endstream> tags and save to a binary file.  I suspect that the thing is an image.  Why don't you use a python PDF reader library?

just wanted to ccreate this data in arraybuffer

was still thinking in python when posting that; but I would believe the theory still holds for javascript.
